# Can I configure EtherCAT slave as S/W?

Tags: modbus, plc, ethercat

I am looking at `EtherCAT`.
I am using embedded `Linux`.
`etherlab` and `SOEM` have been compiled to test that the EtherCAT master functionality is possible.
But I could not find anything about the EtherCAT slave(S/W).

First of all, etherlab had only master function.
`SOES` also required specific hardware(Lan9252, twrk60).(https://github.com/OpenEtherCATsociety/SOES/tree/master/soes/hal)

I think ethercat slave is also possible if ethercat master is available with ethernet port.
Is EtherCAT slave a physical hardware (device) unconditionally required, unlike the EtherCAT master?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EtherCAT Slave requires physical `ESC`(EtherCAT Slave Controller).